# What's the recommend code for koa-ejs using koa2?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I planed use ejs in koa2, my codes were like as blelow:

```
render(app, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'views-ejs'),
  layout: 'layout',
  viewExt: 'ejs',
  cache: false,
  debug: true
});

app.use(function *() {
  yield this.render('index',{
    title: 'koa2 title',
    viewClass: 'landing',
    targetAuthLevel:'',
    authorizationLevel:'6',
    ngController: 'landingController'
  });
});
```

But, I get the below warning, would you tell me what's codes are recommended? please.

> koa deprecated Support for generators will been removed in v3. See the
>   documentation for examples of how to convert old middleware
>   https://github.com/koajs/koa/tree/v2.x#old-signature-middleware-v1x

Comment: If you're using Koa 2, you should be switching from generator functions to using `async/await`. You can read more about it by going to the link that was posted in that warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [README](https://github.com/koajs/ejs/blob/master/README.md):

**Workaround for Koa 2**

```
npm install co --save
```

Then...

```
import co from 'co';
import render from 'koa-ejs';

render(app, options);
app.context.render = co.wrap(app.context.render);

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    await ctx.render(view, locals);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this error with updating koa-ejs to "next" version:

```
$ npm rm -S koa-ejs
$ npm i -S koa-ejs@next
```

- `rm` alias for `remove` command
- `i` alias for `install` command
- `-S` alias for `--save` key