# cannnot find render() on Koa context

Tags: node.js, typescript, redirect, koa, koa2

I am new to koa@2 and I am trying to redirect to a specific page. I am able to redirect to a static page, but I want to send some data to that page to display. I searched for the ways to do this and found ctx(Koa Context) has a method render(), that takes two args(1st-page url, 2nd - locals(our data)).

I tried doing:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const render = require('koa-ejs');
const path = require('path');

const app = new Koa();
render(app, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'view'),
  layout: 'template',
  viewExt: 'html',
  cache: false,
  debug: true
});

app.use(async function (ctx) {
  await ctx.render('user');
});

app.listen(7001);
```

and this:

```
import co from 'co';
import render from 'koa-ejs';

render(app, options);
app.context.render = co.wrap(app.context.render);

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    await ctx.render(view, locals);
});
```

from : [here](https://github.com/koajs/ejs/blob/master/README.md)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976834/whats-the-recommend-code-for-koa-ejs-using-koa2)

but I always get property render does not exist on ctx.
I tried changing the type of ctx from BaseContex to IRouter but the issued remaind same.
I feel I need to attach the render property to ctx, but I dont know how to do it.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the first way:
The second parameter for `ctx.render` is your data

**index.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const render = require('koa-ejs');
const path = require('path');

const app = new Koa();
render(app, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'view'),
  layout: 'template',
  viewExt: 'html',
  cache: false,
  debug: true
});

app.use(async function (ctx) {
  await ctx.render('user', { a: 'apple', b: 'ball', c: 'cat' });
});

app.listen(7001);
```

On the same level, you need to have a `view` folder which has `template.html` since you are specifying the layout as template and viewExt as html

Here's a sample for template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>THIS IS THE TEMPLATE!!!</h1>
    <h2><%= a %></h2>
    <h2><%= b %></h2>
    <h2><%= c %></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, thought it would be better to post the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "stovrflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.5.1",
    "koa-ejs": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```